# cookies import to another browser

Tags: json, csv, netscape

I recently formatted my computer and saved the txt of all cookies from my old browser and now I want to import them all to my chrome so I don't have to log in to sites I was already logged in like steam, gmail, netflix and others could someone help me I've tried in every way to import my cookies to chrome and so far nothing thanks
And I forgot to mention I've tried all the ways to import cookies and so far nothing has been required

Cookies editor, This was just an example of all the other extensions that tried and nothing was to automatically log everything the way I wanted it to happen

Answer (score 0):

User Cookiebro or cookie txt to export all cookie of browser

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).